# Bulk find and replace same values of in cells of a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to create an Excel VBA function to  search values of column A  and find  same cells  in column  H, and replace these  cells  in   B2:F6 with  values of J2:N4.

My Input File:

[image: My Input File Format Image]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output Image]

I have tried  the following VBA code but it doesn't  work. it finds and replace the values of column Replace1 and ignores Replace 2,3,... .

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
'Update 20140722
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
    InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what do you mean? You used a breakpoint and stepped thru it, right? Where did it do something unexpected?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by ' and replace these cells in B2:F6 with values of J2:N4.'

Comment: Because the headers of both datasets are the same, you may benefit from VLOOKUP instead of looping trough each cell. You could do all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like both datasets got same headers so you can benefit from that. If the headers are always the same and same sorting, just copy whole row:

```
Sub test()
'if headers of both datasets are always the same and sorted the same way, just copy whole row

Dim rngDestiny As Range
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim RowN As Long
Dim LR As Long

Set rngSource = Range("I2:M4")
Set rngFind = Range("H2:H4")
Set rngDestiny = Range("B2:F6")

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non-blank cell in column f-name

For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    'check if the value of f-name exists in column FIND
        If .CountIf(rngFind, Range("A" & i).Value) > 0 Then
            'there is a match, get row number and copy
            RowN = .Match(Range("A" & i).Value, rngFind, 0)
            rngSource.Rows(RowN).Copy rngDestiny.Rows(i - 1) 'minus 1 because our first row of data starts with i=2!!!
        End If
    End With
Next i

Set rngSource = Nothing
Set rngFind = Nothing
Set rngDestiny = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]